# TTNavigator on IPad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, three20, ttnavigator

I want to start using THree20's TTNavigator in my app, however I read  [here](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/web/ttnavigator-secrets) that it shouldn't be used on IPad.

I don't really get the explanation, and what using url browsing mechanism has to do the with the IPad screen size.

Did anyone encountered problem with TTNavigator on IPad ?

I don't want to start using to later find out I have problems running the app on an IPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that TTNavigator is written so that it adds a TTNavigationController to the application's window.  You can use it in this fashion if you'd like and it will work but that's not how most developers want to use it on the iPad.  We want to be able to have a a TTNavigator control the view hierarchy in one (if not both) of the view controller(s) in a split view.

Because TTNavigator is designed to work automatically on the app's key UIWindow it doesn't directly support being added as a view controller in a UISplitViewController.

You can hack Three20 to make it work or you can wait a few more weeks for official support from the Three20 developers.

Comment: Official support should be out in a couple weeks ? where did you hear about that ? anyway, if I understand correctly then, there is no reason why I can't start using TTNavigator now, and if in the future I would want to use UISplitViewController and Three20 would implement it, I would change my code a little bit. Correct ?

Comment: Take a look at the latest Three20 releases yesterday(?).  There's been changes to TTBaseNavigator and the TTCatalog sample is has a SplitCatalogController which inherits from TTSplitViewController.

Comment: I'm looking into it myself.  Good luck.

Comment: btw, do they have a static library you take or do you always download the latest code and overwrite the files at your working directory ? Thanks!

Comment: The Three20 project builds as static libraries which are linked against your app.  I've only been using Three20 for a few weeks so I haven't had to worry about messing with my repo clone.  I've just used the provided Python scripts to add it to my project.  [link](http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project)

Answer (score 2):

The iPad has a larger screen to accommodate more than one view at a time, as an example, look at `UISplitViewController`.

The point being made is that `TTNavigator` expects to control the whole screen, meaning only one view will be visible at a time, which almost (but not entirely) goes against the philosophy of the iPad.

iPad users expect to be able to see and do more on an iPad than they would on an iPhone because of the larger screen size. Larger size means more space for multiple touches, more space for extra content and information and interactivity.

There's no technical reason why you shouldn't use `TTNavigator` on an iPad - only usability / user experience reasons.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I still don't 100% get it. If I wanted to show UISplitViewController, couldn't I just map a url to it ? TTNavigator as far as I know (which is not much as I'm new to it) maps to controllers and not to views. I had the idea that after TTNavigator finds the correct controller (using mapping) all it does is calling the correct controller's initializer and then pushing it to screen. Please correct me if I'm wrong.